# ASP.NET How To make the content container of an accordion pane invisible?

Tags: asp.net

is there any way to make the content container of an Ajax accordion invisible ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with setting display:none to its content. Example code is bellow:

```
$find("Accordion_ID").get_Pane(0).content.style.display = "none";
```

Comment: Did you receive any JavaScript errors? Can you paste the code that you have used as well as some markup? I have successfully hidden the content of a test accordion with the upper code.